# Calling an Asynchronous Async/Await Method Recursively

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, recursion, async-await

```
private bool _secondRequest;

public async Task<UserModel> RunSomeMethodAsync(UserModel model, bool mode = true)
{
    // Some code here...

    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    var response = await client.SendAsync(request);            
    var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    if (responseContent != "[]\r")
    {
        return await ProcessThisStringAsync(responseContent);
    {
    else if (responseContent == "[]\n" && !_secondRequest)
    {
        _secondRequest = true;
        await RunSomeMethodAsync(model, false)  // Run same method, different param
    }

    return model.Error = "An error has occurred";
}
```

Unless I missed something obvious, this should work using synchronous code. Will this version run asynchronously? I thought of adding a Task.Delay(1000) but that seemed kinda' kludgy.

Comment: Do you mean you want to run it in parallel? This is already async.

Comment: I want to wait for the first response and it it's not empty, process it and stop. If empty, change the param and run it again, to get a second response, and process it.

Comment: That's what it'll do. I've noticed you're returning a string, when you should be returning a model (and same goes for calling it recursively - it's possible you want `return await RunSomeMethodAsync(model, false)`). What issue are you running into exactly? This will do exactly as you say once the compile errors are resolved

Comment: Not to worry about compile errors. I shortened it for display here. My concern is that while stepping through it, I thought I saw tasks overlapping each other (Looked like the second method call starting before the first finished.)

Comment: It's possible the cause is something external to this code, but `await` will work exactly as you're intending it to - the second invocation of `RunSomeMethodAsync` is guaranteed to execute after `ReadAsStringAsync()`

Comment: @FredChateau Of course the second method starts before the first finishes.  You call the method from the body of the first invocation, the first invocation isn't *allowed* to finish until after the second method call has finished.

Comment: Note the second method called after the return keyword has been changed. That is closer to the real code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will this version run asynchronously?

Yes.

> I thought of adding a Task.Delay(1000) but that seemed kinda' kludgy.

Yeah, don't do that. Unless you *have* to for some reason (like rate limits on the remote service).

Comment: Hey, good catch...  I discovered the remote service was rate limiting me, and that's why I was having trouble. Need to slow it down some, but leaving the asynchronous code in place.

Answer (score 0):

> Unless I missed something obvious, this should work synchronously.

It does not work synchronously.  Why *would* it work synchronously?  The method itself is asynchronous, and you're `await`ing it, which is an asynchronous operation.

> What to do to run it asynchronously?

Do what you're already doing.

Comment: I meant a synchronous version of the workflow would work. I was a little concerned about whether the asynchronous version would.

Comment: @FredChateau What workflow?  And why would it work synchronously?

Comment: If you remove all the asynchronous code (async/await) it does what it's supposed to do synchronously. It's somewhat easier for me to understand, or at least to visualize how one step occurs, then the next step follows after completion of step one. I guess I don't have a good feel for the awaits, because I was concerned it wouldn't wait to start the second request until the first request completed. And that kinda' was the problem I was having. The second request started so fast, it got blocked by the remote service -- a tribute to the efficiency of asynchronous code.